# Как создать Donut Chart в связке с ListView?

Tags: flutter

Необходимо создать две страницы без использования Firebase.
На первой странице ListView в котором перечислены категории, на второй Donut Chart, который получает значения с ListView и разделяет эти категории соответственно. Подскажите, как такое реализовать? Куда копать? Может есть примеры?
P.S > Заранее благодарен

Comment: Можете использовать [PieChart](https://pub.dev/packages/pie_chart). Для пониманияминя проблемы выложите код на [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true).

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас модно делать на tabbed_view. Данные хранить в стейте виджета.

https://pub.dev/packages/tabbed_view